# Unable to skip some method in tornado python test class

Tags: python, tornado, python-unittest

I am writing unit test cases for tornado using AsyncHTTPTestCase class. Previously my class skips the method(on cyclone) which did not start from test. I actually created certain methods just for mocking up the data, it is running UT on those methods too and then fail them with exception: Return value from test method ignored

My class is :

```
class TestClass(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
      def setUp(self):
        super(TestClass, self).setUp()
        self.create_data = self.builddatafortestcase()

    def tearDown(self):
        settings.UT = False
        super(AsyncHTTPTestCase, self).tearDown()

    def get_app(self):
        return Application([
            ("/", Handler)
        ])
    def test_testcase1:
        -------- some test case
    
    def builddatafortestcase(self):    --- i want this to be skipped
        ------
        build some data
        return data
```

How can i skip this method to run 'builddatafortestcase'??

Answer (score 0):

If UnitTest is picking up methods that don't start with "test" you will have to look at how you are running and loading the tests. Normally (using `python -m tornado.testing`) it will use `unittest.TestLoader`, which has `testMethodPrefix = 'test'` so its `getTestCaseNames` method should only return methods that start with `test`.

You can't use `self.skipTest(reason)` in the function as it will skip all tests.

Instead of returning you could set the instance variable in `builddatafortestcase` and if it's already set `skipTest`, something like this:

```
class TestClass(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestClass, self).setUp()
        self.builddatafortestcase()

    def builddatafortestcase(self):
        if hasattr(self, "create_data"):
            self.skipTest("Not a test")
        # build some data
        self.create_data = data
```

But I would recommend solving the underlying problem with the loader instead...